# How do I loop over a list of files from a visual selection?

Tags: key-bindings, visual-mode

Code in .vimrc which starts graphical Neovim on a filename when pressing `gff`

```
% http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/277918/16920
:nnoremap gff :silent! exec "!gnvim " shellescape('<cfile>') <bar> redraw!<cr>
```

Situation

1. View: a list of files.
2. Highlight some of them.
3. Press `gff`.
4. Wanted: get many gvims of multiple documents open.

---

How do I loop over a list of files from a visual selection?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
:vnoremap gff :<C-U>'<,'>g/^/silent! exec "!gnvim " . shellescape('<cfile>') <bar> redraw!<cr>
```

The mapping is for visual mode, and performs a global on all lines that match `/^/`...have a start. Then the rest is the same.

Since `exec` is run synchronously you will only get one instance at a time and your current vim instance will block waiting for the first launched `gnvim` to end.

To get multiple instances at once you'll need to ether use the OS's background process management ( `&` in unix systems), or use some sort of dispatching system like `screen` or `tmux`. See [tpope's Dispatch plugin](https://github.com/tpope/vim-dispatch).

So assuming you are on a Linux/BSD/OSX system

```
:vnoremap gff :<C-U>'<,'>g/^/silent! exec "!gnvim " . shellescape('<cfile>') . " &" <bar> redraw!<cr>
```

If you are on Windows you can use `START /B program`

```
:vnoremap gff :<C-U>'<,'>g/^/silent! exec "!START /B gnvim " . shellescape('<cfile>') <bar> redraw!<cr>
```

To script this up using OS detection:

```
if has("win32") || has("win64")
  :vnoremap gff :<C-U>'<,'>g/^/silent! exec "!START /B gnvim " . shellescape('<cfile>') <bar> redraw!<cr>
else
  :vnoremap gff :<C-U>'<,'>g/^/silent! exec "!gnvim " . shellescape('<cfile>') . " &" <bar> redraw!<cr>
endif
```

Comment: Are you asking of you can generate line specific mappings? <C-1> does first line? If not, the mapping can be anything usable with normal mode mappings so long as it doesn't undo your visual selection.

Comment: @Masi yes just replace `gff` with `<C-1>` and you should be good.

Comment: I have a feeling its because Ubuntu has Ctrl+1 set to something like moving to the 1st Virtual Desktop which would not be controlled by Vim. That would be considered OT for this question since it's an issue with Ubuntu.

Comment: I would suggest you do this the Vim way and use `<leader>` and then one or more keys. Since `gf` is the "Open file named under cursor, you should use either `gf` or `<leader>gf`. Beyond that, this is OT.

Comment: I extend the even distribution of windows here http://vi.stackexchange.com/q/7637/2923

Comment: I extend your answer to many tabs here http://vi.stackexchange.com/q/7782/2923