# Why Error E172 on Execution?

Tags: vimrc, error

Code

```
"" http://vi.stackexchange.com/a/7787/2923
function! OpenSelectionAsTabs() range
    let tabnr = tabpagenr()
    for line in range(a:firstline, a:lastline)
        execute "tabedit " . getline(line)
        execute "tabp"
    endfor
endfunction

nnoremap <leader>gf :'<,'>call OpenSelectionAsTabs()<CR>
vnoremap <leader>gf :call OpenSelectionAsTabs()<CR>
```

Filelist where I select two files in Visual mode and Press `<leader>gf`

```
/Users/masi/Raspberry Pi/me-hello-yes.tex
/Users/masi/hello.tex
...
```

Output

```
Error detected while processing function OpenSelectionAsTabs:
line    3:
E172: Only one file name allowed: tabedit /Users/masi/Raspberry Pi/me-hello-yes.tex
```

There are several complications such as artifact tabs. 
I think the empty spaces can be one source of the problem.

---

Why is there the error message E172?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to escape the line so that

```
tabedit /Users/masi/Raspberry Pi/me-hello-yes.tex
```

becomes

```
tabedit /Users/masi/Raspberry\ Pi/me-hello-yes.tex
```

Otherwise, `tabedit` sees two filenames `/Users/masi/Raspberry` and `Pi/me-hello-yes.tex`.

You can do this with the function `fnameescape()`:

```
execute "tabedit " . fnameescape(getline(line))
```